# Seeking a matrix with special properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am seeking to explicitly find a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/3})$ with the these properties (if exists):

- $\det A=1$.
- $A^3=e^{2i\pi/3}I$.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, denote $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Note that if $A^3 = \omega I$, each of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ must satisfy $\lambda^3 = \omega I$, which is to say: they must each be a root of the equation $\lambda^3 - \omega I = 0$.

Moreover, we know that the characteristic polynomial $\det(xI - A)$ must be a degree $3$ *with coefficients in $\Bbb Q(\omega)$* whose roots are the eigenvalues of $A$.

From the above two facts (either by listing each of the $3^3$ possibilities or by a Galois-theoretic argument), we can deduce that the characteristic polynomial a suitable $A$ satisfying your second condition can only be the polynomial $p(x) = x^3 - \omega $.  It would follow that the determinant of such a matrix is
$$
\det(A) = p(0) = -\omega \neq 1
$$
Thus, there is no such matrix.

---

**Galois theoretic argument:** Note that the roots $e^{2\pi i/9}, \omega e^{(2\pi i)/9}, \omega^2 e^{(2\pi i)/9}$ are *algebraically indistinguishable* over $\Bbb Q(\omega)$; its Galois group is $S_3$.  In particular, there is no polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ that has one root and not the other two.  So, any polynomial with a root from this set must be of degree at least $3$.